# How to use Find in Files dialog in IntelliJ?

Tags: file, intellij-idea, mask

I am using IntelliJ 2020.2.3 Ultimate Edition and want to search for any occurrence of some string and it works well as long as I do not use the file mask. Not using the mask I get several hits in any kind of files but when I select a file mask, let's say .yml, I get NO hits although it was found previously in *.yml files when I do not use the file mask.
How can I achieve to get hits using the file mask?

[image: Find in Path with selected File mask]

[image: Find in Path without selected File mask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked this with my 2020.2.3 **Community Edition** and it is working when the filter is set as **"*.yaml"** as well as without any filters. (Sorry, I do not have an Ultimate Edition installed with me).

***.yaml**

[image]

**No filters**

[image]

Comment: OMG...just th missing '*' ... LOL

Answer (score 0):

I works as excpeted in IntelliJ IDEA Community and Ultimate Edition.

I guess, that your mask is set to `*.yaml` and the expected hit is in a `*.yml` file or vice versa.
Try to use a comma separated list of file mask to search in both file types:

[image]

Furthermore, make sure the filter is deaktivated and set to `Anywhere`:
[image]